# Don't use session on certain url

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a certain api url that can be loaded, but wont update a user's session "last activity" time.

I've set things up so that my users get logged out if inactive for 60 minutes, via `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()`, `server.session.timeout` and spring security, which works well. Now, I'm trying to build an api call that the client can call to check how long their session has until it expires. But, the crux of the problem is that if I call an api, it will see this as user activity and renew the session for another 60 min, defeating the purpose.

I'm hoping maybe there's a way to disable the use of a session for a certain url. Then I can just manually grab the session id via the cookie sent, manually look up their session object to get the info I need out of it without updating the last activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably best off writing your own session invalidation logic.
You cant manually control the tomcat access time behaviour without a lot of hack work.
You could write a servlet filter that tracks the last time a page(other than the whitelisted pages) was accessed and invalidates sessions that exceed the threshold.

```
public class AccessTimeFilter implements Filter {

    private static final long ACCESS_TIME_WINDOW = 30 * 60 * 1000;//30 Mins
    private static final Set<String> IGNORED_URLS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("/myurl", "/someOtherUrl"));

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Long realLastAccessedTime = (Long) session.getAttribute("realLastAccessedTime");
        if(realLastAccessedTime != null &&
                realLastAccessedTime < (System.currentTimeMillis() - ACCESS_TIME_WINDOW)){
            session.invalidate();
        }

        doFilter(req, res, chain);

        String url = request.getServletPath();
        if(!IGNORED_URLS.contains(url)){
            session.setAttribute("realLastAccessedTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
```